# Regex allowing two same alphabetic characters

Tags: jquery

this is my first time positing.  I am looking for a jquery validation for regex where if you type in your name that starts with "JJohn" it should allow it.  And also something like "Johnn".  My attempt is below.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\bs-']+$/i
```

Comment: that looks about right? do you mean NOT Allow it?

Comment: How is this scenario different from allowing any alphabet to appear in the string? Unless you mean you are only allowing double repeats and not triple, but that doesn't make a lot of sense anyway.

Comment: I meant is to allow the field to have two same letters in a name.  At the moment validation is throwing the error for it.

Comment: What validation is erroring? What have you set that only double-characters are failing?

Answer (score 0):

To match two or more of the same character, use groups:

```
/(\w)\1+/
```

This would capture any string where two word-characters appeared in sequence.